# Is there a way to use Firebug's console.log from Firefox's cfx?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Using the Add-on SDK's `cfx run` command, is it possible to get it to log to Firebug's console instead of the command line one from the main add-on code or content scripts?

Comment: console.log messages from web content should show up in Firebug or the web console as normal. There is no way currently to get console.log statements from content script or addon code into firebug - I think that would require a Firebug plugin or possibly use of ChromeBug.

Comment: @canuckistani: I've tried Chromebug, but it still goes to the terminal.

Comment: Right - as I said there is no way currently to do this. Personally I prefer seeing messages from my code printed to the terminal - it's better than trying to use the console window. YMMV.

Comment: Agreed, in general.  But one nice part is easy dumping and introspection of objects ("`[object Object]`") or DOM nodes and being able to click on the to figure out which one it is.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, '    '));

Comment: Yep, good, but it's not Firebug :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented property `unsafeWindow`.  As its name implies, this is a BAD IDEA.  But, as you are only using it for debugging everything should be fine.  Please remove these statements when releasing your addon.

```
unsafeWindow.console.log("Hello, firebug!");
```

If you want to make all console calls go to firebug you can put the following in your content script.

```
console = unsafeWindow.console;
```

If you just want log

```
console.log = unsafeWindow.console.log
```

**Note:** When I was running this on a `contentScriptWhen: "start"` page-mod I noticed that Firebug hadn't loaded into the console object yet.  So if you are using `contentScriptWhen: "start"` you may need a slight delay before accessing the console.

Comment: Marked correct with the caveat emptor that I haven't tested it.  I've moved on from the project.